# Read AVAsset into frames and compile back to video

Tags: ios, objective-c, avassetwriter, avassetreader

everyone! The idea in my project is to gather a video, split it into frames, then apply specific effect frame by frame(not the topic) and then compile everything back.

Using following code I am able to read the video into frames and pass them into array:

```
//initialize avassetreader
AVAsset *avAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
AVAssetReader *reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:avAsset error:&error];

//get video track
NSArray *videoTracks = [avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [videoTracks objectAtIndex:0];

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];

AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *asset_reader_output = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:videoTrack outputSettings:options];

[reader addOutput:asset_reader_output];
[reader startReading];
```

Next, as I said above I read the track frame by frame

```
//while there is something to read
while ( [reader status]==AVAssetReaderStatusReading ) { 


    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [asset_reader_output copyNextSampleBuffer];
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);

    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    //Generate image to edit
    unsigned char* pixel = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context=CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little|kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage* myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
    [photos addObject:myImage];

}
```

I am able to put everything into an array but I need to compile everything back into a video track, compile it with audio from original track an then save. However, I couldn't find any useful information on the web. Please, help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that in your frame-by-frame code there are a few memory leaks. Specifically you need to release the CGImageRef, your color space, the context, and the sample buffer. So if you're still using this (or if someone else comes and uses this) make sure to check the memory management.

Comment: You should really look into using GPUImage for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have an array of images, AVAssetWriter is your friend.